# My code crashes console, error with React state updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm getting an error

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor).

Here I have my `TodoItems` with state, where I store the list of entries:

```
var TodoItems = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            entries: this.props.entries
        };
    }
    ...
});
```

Here I have my `removeItem` function, where I iterate through list, and then use `prop` to update the `state`:

```
removeItem: function(key){
    var itemArray = this.state.entries;
    for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
        if (itemArray[i.key] === key) {
            itemArray.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    this.setState({
        entries: itemArray
    });
}
```

Here is my `render` function, where I also have `createTasks` function which is responsible for creating the items in `TodoList`. I think my problem may lay in here?

```
render: function() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var _removeItem = this.removeItem;

    function createTasks(item) {
        return (
            <li key={item.key}>
                {item.text}
                <button onClick = {_removeItem(item.key)} className= "remove"> 
                    Remove
                </button>
            </li>
        );
    }

    var listItems = todoEntries.map(createTasks);

    return (
        <ul className="theList">
            {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Here is the actual `TodoList` component, where I assingn items with unique keys.

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    },

    addItem: function(e) {
        var itemArray = this.state.items;

        itemArray.push({
            text: this._inputElement.value,
            key: Date.now()
        });

        this.setState({
            items: itemArray
        });

        this._inputElement.value = "";

        e.preventDefault();
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="todoListMain">
                <div className="header">
                    <form onSubmit = {this.addItem}>
                        <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                               placeholder="enter task">
                        </input>
                        <button type="submit">add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoList/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your onclick event executed on compilation. You should pass a function, not a result as this:

```
<button onClick = {this.removeItem (or _removeItem} data-key={key}
```

Also, bind this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this) in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your mistake is that you're passing the items as a prop and then trying to update the elements from your child component(this is TodoItem component) and you shouldn't do this.
The way you could accomplish your mission is by making a function in the parent component (TodoList) for removing an Item. Then you could pass that function as a prop and firing It from inside the child component.

Something like this:

For a start, you could try an ES6 solution for removing an element from your entries. You can use the filter method, that will return a new array with all the elements of the array that satisfy the condition. **Then you would need to assign this new array to your state entries object.**

In TodoList component you should create a new function:

```
removeItem(key){
    this.state.items.filter( (item) => item.key != key )
}
```

Then you should pass It down:

```
<TodoItem deleteItem={(key) => this.removeItem(key)} entries={this.state.items}/>
```

and then in your TodoItem you should call that function:

```
<button onClick={this.props.deleteItem(key)}
```

Also, if you want, you could try defining your createTask function from outside your render function in your TodoItem component.

My implementation might not work as is, but my recommendation is to handle It like that. Remember that React is about top down data flow.

Hope It helps man.